# Can't see my dedicated video card

Tags: hybrid-graphics, gpu-driver, vgaswitcheroo

when I hit `lspci -nn | grep VGA` I get only the intel video card, but not the AMD one, is it beacuse I have discreet video card activated?

```
sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0
1:DIS: :DynOff:0000:0d:00.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't see it because the `lspci` line does not contain `VGA`.

If you run

```
lspci -nn | grep -E 'VGA|Display'
```

you will see both cards.

If you are unsure what to filter, run it without `grep`

```
lspci -nn
```

Comment: Another common word for video cards for which you can search is "3D".

Comment: `3D` is only for Nvidia ;-)

Comment: Ah, okay? Yeah, that might be true. So Intel calls them "VGA", AMD "Display" and Nvidia "3D" something? Interesting.

Comment: You are almost correct.